# Why onclientclick do a postback?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp button with no onclick event but only onclientclick. This call a javascript function in a iframe in which a video is playing;

each time I click the javascript function is called but also the video restart which means the  page is reloaded.

How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

return false from your onclientclick.

```
OnClientClick="LoadVideo();return false;"
```

Answer (score 3):

add

```
 return false;
```

to you function.